How do i automate a gitlab runner setup using ansible?
Problem:
I'm working on an Ansible playbook to manage GitLab Runner registration and configuration. The playbook should:
Register a GitLab Runner and extract its token and ID.
Template a config file with the extracted variables, including a marker (####) at the end.
On subsequent runs, it should find the #### marker in the existing config, remove everything after it, and append new configuration content.
However, on rerunning the playbook, the #### marker is getting removed inadvertently, causing the config to be incorrect. Specifically, the issue arises when default configurations are added back, resulting in the #### marker being deleted, and the new configurations are not appended correctly.
To visualize it:
<start of template 1>
Template 1 
bla blabla
bla 
bla
####
<end of template 1>
(then i rerun and the default config gets put in so now the config file looks like this:

<start of template 1>
Template 1 
bla blabla
bla 
bla
####
<end of template 1>
<Start of default config 2>
bla bla
bla
bla
<End of default config 2>


so basically the default config deletes the marker #### upon regstering
Wanted output:
So it should see the marker ("####") on the first template, remove the default config after extracting the token and id, and template to a config.tmp with token and id then append that config.tmp to the "main" config.toml
<start of template 1>
Template 1 
bla blabla
bla 
bla
####
<end of template 1>
(then i rerun and the default config gets put in so now the config file looks like this:

<start of template 1>
Template 1 
bla blabla
bla 
bla
<end of template 1>
<Start of template 2>
bla bla
bla
bla
####
<End of template 2>

Here is part of the playbook that is in play:
(This verison is below gitlab 15.6 so it works)
- name: register runner
  command: |
      docker compose run --rm runner register \
        --non-interactive \
        --url "{{ gitlab_runner_url }}" \
        --registration-token "{{ gitlab_runner_reg_token }}" \
        --name "{{ gitlab_runner_name }}"
        --executor "{{ gitlab_runner_executor }}" \
        --docker-image "{{ gitlab_runner_docker_image }}" \
  args:
    chdir: "{{ gitlab_path_dir }}"
  when: register_runner_confirm.user_input | lower == 'y'
  register: gitlab_runner_registred

- name: extract runner token
  shell: "grep -Po '(?<=token = \")[^\"]*' {{ gitlab_path_config }} | tail -1"
  register: gitlab_runner_config_token

- name: extract runner id
  shell: "grep -Po '(?<=id = )[0-9]+' {{ gitlab_path_config }} | tail -1"
  register: gitlab_runner_config_id

- name: clear config file if marker file does not exist
  copy:
    content: ""
    dest: "{{ gitlab_path_config }}"
  when: not marker_file_result.stat.exists

- name: template runner config with variables
  template:
    src: gitlab-runner-config.j2
    dest: "{{ gitlab_path_config }}"
  vars:
    gitlab_runner_token: "{{ gitlab_runner_config_token.stdout }}"
    gitlab_runner_id: "{{ gitlab_runner_config_id.stdout | int }}"
  when: not marker_file_result.stat.exists

- name: Read existing config content
  slurp:
    src: "{{ gitlab_path_config }}"
  register: existing_config_content
  when: marker_file_result.stat.exists

- name: Find last occurrence of #### and get line number
  shell: "grep -n '####' {{ gitlab_path_config }} | tail -1 | cut -d: -f1"
  register: last_section_line
  changed_when: false
  when: marker_file_result.stat.exists

### Not sure if it works since im not getting to this part
#- name: Remove content after last #### and store in temporary file
#  shell: |
#    last_line="{{ last_section_line.stdout | default('$') }}"
#    sed "${last_line},\$d" {{ gitlab_path_config }} > {{ gitlab_path_dir }}/existing_config.tmp
#  when: marker_file_result.stat.exists

#- name: Template new runner config
#  template:
#    src: gitlab-runner-config.j2
#    dest: "{{ gitlab_path_dir }}/new_config.tmp"
#  vars:
#    gitlab_runner_token: "{{ gitlab_runner_config_token.stdout }}"
#    gitlab_runner_id: "{{ gitlab_runner_config_id.stdout | int }}"
#  when: marker_file_result.stat.exists

### Not sure if it works since im not getting to this part
#- name: Concatenate cleaned config with temporary config
#  shell: | 
#   "cat <(sed '{{ last_section_line.stdout }}q' {{ gitlab_path_config }}) {{ gitlab_path_dir }} #/
#   /gitlab-runner-config.tmp > {{ gitlab_path_config }}.new /
#   && mv {{ gitlab_path_config }}.new {{ gitlab_path_config }}" /
#  when: marker_file_result.stat.exists
  
- name: Remove temporary files
  file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: absent
  loop:
    - "{{ gitlab_path_dir }}/gitlab-runner-config.tmp"

- name: template registry config file
  template:
    src: registry-config.j2
    dest: "{{ gitlab_path_registry_mirror }}"


- name: create marker file to indicate first run is completed
  file:
    path: "{{ gitlab_path_dir }}/.first_run_completed"
    state: touch
  when: not marker_file_result.stat.exists


Attempted Solutions:
Initial Playbook Logic:
Registered the runner and extracted the token and ID.
Cleared the config file if it was the first run.
Added the #### marker at the end of the config.
On subsequent runs, attempted to remove content after #### and append new configuration.
However, the #### marker was being deleted, causing issues in maintaining the correct config structure.
Shell Command for Removing Content After ####:
Used sed to find the last occurrence of #### and delete everything after it.
The command sed -i '/####/,$d' {{ gitlab_path_config }} worked initially but sometimes failed to correctly find and maintain the #### marker.
Updated Approach:
Read the existing config content.
Decoded the base64-encoded content.
Found the last occurrence of #### and removed content after it.
Temporarily stored the remaining content.
Created new runner configuration and appended it correctly.
Despite these attempts, I was still facing issues with the #### marker being removed incorrectly and the configurations not appending as expected.
Expectation:
I expected the playbook to correctly identify the #### marker without removing it on the subsequent runs, remove everything after it on subsequent runs, and append new configurations while retaining the #### marker. This would ensure that the configuration file remains correctly structured across multiple playbook runs as that is my end goal.

Did you consider using the
Ansible blockinfile module?
There's some nice examples of managed blocks. And it's also a good practice
to not just put markers such as #### but something clear showing that
the file is managed by Ansible, for example:
- name: Add mappings to /etc/hosts
  ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
    path: /etc/hosts
    block: |
      {{ item.ip }} {{ item.name }}
    marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{ item.name }}"
  loop:
    - { name: host1, ip: 10.10.1.10 }
    - { name: host2, ip: 10.10.1.11 }
    - { name: host3, ip: 10.10.1.12 }

By the way, just found this
Gitlab runner installation Gist
which may help you, as it looks similar to your needs.

Thank you for your response, i have not tried using block in file as this is my first time using ansible. But ill look into that and hopefully find a solution!
